# Why does the addEventListener property does not work on a dynamic HTMLcollection object?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, htmlcollection

I am working on a chrome extension and trying to add an event listener to a getElementsByClassName variable, in which elements are added dynamically using template strings.

I have tried a lot of changes in the code, but the code doesn't work.

The code is supposed to delete the targeted element from the array "recipeList", storing the array in localStorage and then render the updated array "recipeList" using template string to the HTML code again.

**DELETE BUTTON Function**

```
let delBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("del-btn");

for(let i = 0; i < delBtn.length; i++) { 
    delBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        recipeList.splice(i, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("recipeList", JSON.stringify(recipeList));
        recipeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipeList"));
        render(recipeList);
        if(!recipeList.length) {
            tabBtn.style.width = "100%";
            delAllBtn.style.display = "none";
        }
    }); 
}
```

**RENDER CODE**

```
function render(list) {
    let recipeURL = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        recipeURL += `
        <div class="mb-2 row">
            <div class="col-1 num-btn">
                ${i+1}
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
                <div class="recipe-url">
                    <a target="_blank" href="${list[i]}">
                        ${list[i]}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 del-btn">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        `
    }
    urlList.innerHTML = recipeURL;
    console.log(delBtn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render, you create new `.del-btn` which are not included in your first `let delBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("del-btn");`.

Each time you create new `.del-btn`, you should also add a new listener.

```js
function render(list) {
    let recipeURL = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        recipeURL += `
        <div class="mb-2 row">
            <div class="col-1 num-btn">
                ${i+1}
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
                <div class="recipe-url">
                    <a target="_blank" href="${list[i]}">
                        ${list[i]}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 del-btn">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        `
    }
    urlList.innerHTML = recipeURL;
    console.log(delBtn);

    Array.from(urlList.querySelectorAll('.del-btn')).forEach((btn, i) => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('.del-btn index: ' + i))
    })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But how am I supposed to do that, I tried to add event listener to the parent element and use event.target to get the triggered element but according to my code, I want the index of the event.target, but whenever I any click the button, only the 0th child node gets selected. i am trying to get hold of the index by using `let i = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, event.target)` and `let i = event.target.index` but none of them work.

Comment: I added an example. Tell me if that's more clear.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed useful, your code worked like a charm.